# entity_reference autocomplete: Allow multiple target_types

Tags: 8, entities

I'm creating a new custom entity and would like the ability for my `entity_reference` autocomplete field to be able to allow selecting from any arbitrary set of entities.

For example, let's say I would like the available autocomplete options to draw from:

- two node types (page, my_custom_node)
- users
- the terms in the Tags taxonomy vocabulary

Can anyone lend me insight as to how this might be accomplished? I'm a somewhat experienced Drupal 7 developer, but Drupal 8 has been quite an uphill climb for me and I'm afraid that not all of the new concepts are clear enough to me yet to accomplish this task on my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

entity_reference fields do not support multiple target types, never have, also not in Drupal 7 :) So you can't have an autocomplete for that as it couldn't be stored then.

However, you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference, which stores entity type and ID in a field and the default widget it provides is a combination of select and auto-complete field to select the type and the specific entity.